# IE8: parseInt('07') vs parseInt('08')

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, parseint

Found out a strange thing in IE8:

```
parseInt('01')
//1
parseInt('02')
//2
parseInt('03')
//3
/*...*/
parseInt('07')
//7
parseInt('08')
//0 !!!
parseIntr('09')
//9 ok
```

Can someone clarify?

Comment: you forgot to use a radix

Comment: All right, using radix heps. Can someone post the answer so I could mark it as answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use radix

```
parseInt('08', 10)
//8
```